# synchronized keyword in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I create a two threads `a1`, `a2` from class A that extends Thread class. Class A declare two constructors and run method that is synchronized. When I write the code in this form the two thread sometimes start at the same time although the `run` method is declared as synchronized and I am getting result like

```
0 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 11 6 12 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Code:

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        A t = new A () ;       
        A a1 = new A (t) ;      
        A a2 = new A (t) ;

        a1.start();
        a2.start();
    }    
}

class A extends Thread {
    public A()  {
        super() ;
    }

    public A(Thread th )  {
        super(th) ;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized  void run () {   
        for (int i = 0; i <13; i++) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");             
        }    
    }
}
```

But when I create two threads via class Thread not A,

```
Thread a1 = new Thread (t);
Thread a2 = new Thread (t);
```

the synchronized method `run` work and two threads do not start at the same time always giving result

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

My question: Why synchronized keyword do not work when I create a two thread from class A (although I define a two constructors) and work when I create a two thread from Thraed class?

Comment: How do you see that threads start at the same time in the first case? Do you see intermingling outputs? Could you please show us that output?

Comment: I can assure you that `synchronized` is indeed working properly. You are synchronizing on the `Thread` objects themselves, which is a bit pointless really.

Comment: my friend synchronized works properly always. Now your mistake is in understanding over here **Thread a1 = new Thread (t); Thread a2 = new Thread (t);**  small description = Here you are creating two different object having two different lock right?  so why one thread will wait do you got this?? Both thread have different lock. got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run thread by calling `start()` at some point it invokes its `run()` method which in `Thread` class looks like this:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

This code is responsible for executing code from `run` method of `Runnable target` object passed in `new Thread(Runnable target)` constructor.

But you overrode `Thread#run()` in your `A` class. So now `start()` method invokes `A#run` (because of polymorphism), which means it never invokes `target.run()` (in your case - `t.run()` since `t` was passed as `A` thread target).
Now even if `A#run` method is `synchronized`, because each thread invokes it on separate instance (thread object itself) no synchronization happens because threads are not using *common* lock/monitor.

You ware getting correct results only because sometimes one thread was able to do its full work before other started.

---

To avoid such confusing problems (and many other) **don't extend Thread at all**. Create class which implements Runnable and pass it to `Thread` instance.

Think of `Runnable` as *task*, and `Thread` as *worker* which should execute that task. Your job is to describe *what* worker should do (take this, put it there), not *how* (bend your knees, grab that, ..).

Answer (score 0):

You can not be sure that threads start simultaneously unless you use synchronizers like `Semaphore`, `CountDownLatch` or `CyclicBarrier`.
`synchronized` keyword itself is used to protect the **same** object (method or block of code) from concurrent access. In your code `synchronized` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the modified code to handle your issue.

```
public class RunnableDemo {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread (new MyRunnable(lock));      
        Thread t2 = new Thread (new MyRunnable(lock));      

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }    
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    Object lock = new Object();
    public MyRunnable(Object lock){
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {  
        synchronized(lock){
            for (int i = 0; i <13; i++) {
                System.out.print(i+" ");             
            }  
        }           
    }
}
```

1. A shared lock is created in main class : `RunnableDemo`
2. Two Threads have been created by passing `MyRunnable` object, which implements `Runnable` interface. Instead of extending `Thread` to create new `Thread`, passing `Runnable` interface implementation to `Thread` constructor is preferred approach.
3. Both Threads have been started. Since they share common lock, only one `Thread` complete `run()` block
4. Now you can see output is in right sequence as below:

   ```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
   ```

I have just showcases basic locking mechanism. For advanced version of multi threading, you can refer to [high level concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) tutorial.